# Playing a sound file with Arduino Uno Wifi

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-uno-wifi

I have an Arduino Uno Wifi (Rev2) and I want to play a sound file. I found two libraries so far but neither of them work. The TMRpcm library (https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/tmrpcm/) only works on the base Arduino Uno and anther library called AudioZero (https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/audiozero/) does not seem to be compatible with Arduino Uno Wifi.
Is there any other library that I could use to play a sound file. I have an SD card attached and a library that can read in a .wav file but no library to actually output the sounds on a basic speaker.

I need to use the Arduino Uno Wifi for what I am trying to achieve since communicating with the internet is crucial.
Using a base Uno with a wifi attachment did not prove to be promising since the attachment acted as it's own board and need to be flashed.

Comment: The Uno a) doesn't have analog outputs and b) only a tiny RAM. You better look for a more suitable microcontroller or at least a hardware extension to do the job of buffering and playing the output signal.

Comment: Hi @SimSon thank you for your reply. Do you have any recommendations? I have only used the Arduino Uno so far and I am not very familiar with other microcontrollers.

Comment: I have no experience with playing audio files on microcontrollers, but I'd personally start with a controller that has a reasonably large RAM (e.g. ESP32) and an external DAC.

Comment: If the controller is compatible with the Arduino environment, there shouldn't be much difference from how you would program the Uno

Answer (score 1):

No sounds library seems to exist that is compatible with the architecture of the Arduino Uno Wifi specifically. Other micro-controllers need to be looked into.